# UniWebView does not work on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-webview, uniwebview

I'm finding with uniwebview on Android it often does not load the page correctly.

What I'm doing is isntantiating a prefab with the uniwebview script attached to it, assigning it various values then calling 'Load' on it.

For whatever reason very often (usually after the second boot up of the app after a fresh install) the webpage does not load, I don't get any errors (uniwebview informs me it was successful) however I don't see the webview show up in game.

Worse yet the webview appears to actually be loaded but not visible as it blocks all inputs to the game screen. If the app is allowed to hae portrait/landscape configurations and I switch it from portrait to landscape the webview appears. I'm very confused by this and not sure how to fix it.

The issue appears to e caused by the usage of UniWebViewTransitionEdge in the show function, i.e.: webView.Show(true, UniWebViewTransitionEdge.Bottom, 0.4f); where if I simply show without passing in extra arguments it works fine for the most part.

Comment: are you talking about [this](http://uniwebview.onevcat.com) UniWebView? and what version are you using?

Comment: The latest version of UniWebView 2.0

Comment: So according to the [Unity Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/32461) this would be actually Version 2.9.0 of Oct 03, 2016.